# documentum dql return cabinets where r_accessor_permit > 2

Tags: dql, documentum

Hi all I'm writing a program that is supposed to query a documentum installation to return a list of
the cabinets or folders, i have a query that returns objects in a folder just fine but i am having trouble returning the root or home cabinet's visible cabinets I am trying to say something like

```
  select object_name from dm_cabinet where r_accessor_name = 'user' and r_accessor_permit >2
```

so basically i want to return the objects in the dm cabinet for a given user but only return those which that user has a permission of 3 or higher. is there a way do to that?

is there a way to union the two tables for acl and dm_cabinet

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, either with DQL or with DFC (Java). Whichever approach you choose, I'd recommend using a session that belongs to the actual user for whom you are trying to access cabinets/folders. I would not use a superuser (which could circumvent Documentum's security model).

If you are into coding this in Java anyway, the most flexible solution is to use DFC, or perhaps a combination of DFC and DQL. Once you get an `IDfSysobject` (cabinet, folder or document), you can use the `getPermit()` method which will give you the `int` you're after. Be sure to test this `int` against the static integers in the `IDfACL` interface -- avoid magic numbers.

For instance, put the desired objects into a list.

```
// assuming you have an initialized user session (not covered here)
IDfSession userSession;

List<String> readableCabinetsNames = new ArrayList<String>();

// will only return objects that the current user can see (browse or higher)
String dql = "SELECT r_object_id FROM dm_cabinet";

IDfQuery query = new DfQuery(dql);
IDfCollection coll = query.execute(userSession, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);
while (coll.next()) {
    IDfCabinet cabinet = (IDfCabinet) coll.getTypedObject();
    if (cabinet.getPermit() >= IDfACL.DF_PERMIT_READ) {
        String cabinetName = cabinet.getObjectName();
        readableCabinetsNames.add(cabinetName);
    }
}
```

This is just something from my memory to get you started, and it can be improved - a lot :)

Remember this: Both DQL and DFC will follow the Documentum security model. A user will never see an object for which they have no rights.

Comment: is there a way to do this in .net... select r_object_id will return more objects than the DA see's with the same user login, at least on my end.

Comment: The reason DA returns less cabinets, is that DA reads and interprets the `is_private` attribute from `dm_cabinet`, and so it hides these cabinets from the view. If you want to hide these cabinets as well, add `AND is_private = 0` to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I guess my question was incorrect,when i run the basic select from dm_cabinet it returns all the cabinets including user specific ones , i don't want to include the other user's cabinets. I can see james and chris and lisa's personal cabinets even though im logged in as ryan

Comment: And that is exactly what I answered in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

dm_cabinet is subtype of dm_folder. That could help you. 
If you can make connection to Documentum repository with that specific user credentials, you just need to fetch objects without any filter whether this user can see it since Documetnum respects user rights regarding objects either way you are trying to fetch it.

If you can't make this connection than you need some custom coding. If that's the case I'll update my answer.

Comment: I guess my question was incorrect,when i run the basic select from dm_cabinet it returns all the cabinets including user specific ones , i want to not include the other user's cabinets. I can see james and chris and lisa's personal cabinets even though im logged in as ryan